# How to extract XML value via SQL in SAP HANA?

Tags: xml, hana

I have database table in SAP HANA where one column stores an XML string. I just need one value which is stored in the tags called `<PROPERTY NAME="NAME">` and `</PROPERTY>`. There are several tags with that name. I need the top one. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LINK_PROCESS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" LINK_TYPE="LINK">
    <PROPERTY NAME="NAME">Import XY Data</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">Import XY Data from File</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY NAME="ID">DKV8Y051VOKNVE7MRRYE4AXYK</PROPERTY>
    <LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_PACKAGE">
        <PROPERTY NAME="NAME">Import XY</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">Import XY Data</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="ID">04F3E61B5612439397CE76E3EC271598</PROPERTY>
    </LINK_PROCESS>
    <LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_LINK">
        <PROPERTY NAME="NAME">XYZ</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">XYZ Data</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="ID">7319D3A0196D4510924D32988B189A8E</PROPERTY>
    </LINK_PROCESS>
</LINK_PROCESS>
```

I would like to get the value **Import XY Data** and nothing more. How can I extract this via SAP HANA SQL that it just extracts that value between the tags instead of the whole XML string?

Comment: Which version of HANA are you using? 2.0 SPS01 and SPS02 add support for `SELECT ... FROM XMLTABLE`, which would make your life a lot easier...

Comment: We're using HANA 1.0 SP12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAP HANA 1 (SPS12) doesn't provide methods to directly work with XML expressions/documents. As @mjturner already mentioned, this situation has been improved in HANA 2 by providing XML processing built-in functions.

That means you have to come up with your own way of processing XML to get the value you're interested in. 
Writing a proper XML parser is probably beyond what anyone would like to do in SQLScript, so I would recommend to not try *that*.

Instead, it could be an option to look for a string that is in the `NAME` tag that follows the `LINK_PROCESS type LINK`-tag:

```
<LINK_PROCESS  ... LINK_TYPE="LINK">
<PROPERTY NAME="NAME">Import XY Data</PROPERTY>
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This structure can be looked up via regular expressions and SAP HANA SPS12 does support the `SUBSTRING_REGEXPR()` ([reference documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/1.0.12/en-US/a2f80e8ac8904c13959c69bfc3058f19.html)) function for that.

See https://regex101.com/r/k5FVqU/1 for an example regex that matches the structure.

Putting it into HANA SQL could look like this:

```
with data as (

    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <LINK_PROCESS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" LINK_TYPE="LINK">
    <PROPERTY NAME="NAME">Import XY Data</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">Import XY Data from File</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY NAME="ID">DKV8Y051VOKNVE7MRRYE4AXYK</PROPERTY>
    <LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_PACKAGE">
        <PROPERTY NAME="NAME">Import XY</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">Import XY Data</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="ID">04F3E61B5612439397CE76E3EC271598</PROPERTY>
    </LINK_PROCESS>
    <LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_LINK">
        <PROPERTY NAME="NAME">XYZ</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">XYZ Data</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="ID">7319D3A0196D4510924D32988B189A8E</PROPERTY>
    </LINK_PROCESS>
</LINK_PROCESS>' as XML_DATA FROM DUMMY
)

SELECT 
    SUBSTR_REGEXPR('(<LINK_PROCESS.*LINK_TYPE="LINK">)\s*(<PROPERTY.*NAME="NAME">)(.*)(<\/PROPERTY>)'
                   FLAG 'in' 
                   IN "XML_DATA" 
                   GROUP 3 )
from data;
```

> Import XY Data